# Expire workboxjs cached items based on querystring

Tags: sharepoint, workbox

im using Workbox to pre-cache  & cache resources in my sharepoint project.
ms sharepoint uses a lot of its own js / css out of the box that i would like to be cached.

Sharepoint renders the src tags for js, css with a revision ID appended to the querystring.
somethig like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/15/1046/styles/SuiteNav.css?rev=tyIeEoGrLkQjn4siLhDMLw%3D%3DTAG0"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/1046/initstrings.js?rev=mwvYlbIyUbEbxtCpAg383w%3D%3DTAG0"></script>
```

I would like to expire those resources based on the revision (rev) querystring.
can this be done by anything out of the box in workbox js or i will need something like a custom plugin?

can you point me at the documentation / example ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with resources that are not available at build time, because, for instance, those URLs only exist on the Sharepoint server, then you'll have to use runtime caching to handle them.

I'd recommend going with a cache-first strategy for resources like those that have revisioning information in their URL, since they'll (hopefully!) only change if their URL changes.

In terms of making sure that you eventually expire the older entries, that's a bit trickier to do aggressively. What I'd suggest instead is that you use a more conservative approach to expiration, with a maximum number of entries in your cache that is some multiple of the expected number of URLs that will be valid at any given time. For instance, if you know that there are likely to be ~10 URLs that are the "most recent" at any given time, then configuring cache expiration to start expiring entries once you've reach ~30 or so items in the cache would be reasonable.

Putting that all together, you could configure Workbox's runtime caching as follows ([using the new v3 syntax](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/route-requests)):

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  // Customize this pattern as needed.
  new RegExp('/_layouts/15/1046/'),
  workbox.strategies.cacheFirst({
    cacheName: 'sharepoint-assets',
    plugins: [
      new workbox.expiration.Plugin({maxEntries: 30}),
    ],
  })
);
```

Comment: Thank you Jeff!  
You are correct in your assumption. the resources are not avaliable at build time.
the approach you suggested will do fine in this case. those resources are part of the main product and changes only when a service pack is applied.

for my custom resources  the issue is: there is no build proces in place. They are  stored inside sharepoint server ( version controlled).

items stored inside sharepoint have etag on the response headers. can it be used with workbox in any meaninfull way?
thanks again.

Comment: I don't think the presence of an ETag header will make much of a difference with regards to the service worker's behavior in this case.